# How to center vertically and horizontally in React with Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to center a Button inside of a Card that is in the center of the screen. So far I haven't been able to.

This is wha I have so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #9013FE 15%, #50E3C2 90%)',
    minWidth: '100%',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: '40%',
    minHeight: '20vh',
  },
})

export default function LoginPage () {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.root} spacing={0} align="center" justify="center">
      <Card className={classes.card} align="center" justify="center">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Hello World
        </Button>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

It's centered vertically but not horizontally, when I change other parameter I get it centered horizontally but not vertically.

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK2Dp.png)

Any Ideas?

Best regards.

Answer (score 6):

Use This

```
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";

function Component() {
  return (
    <Stack
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      sx={{ width: 1, height: "100vh" }}
    >
      <CircularProgress />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `alignItems`.

Code Sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-material-ui-centering-0rgqx

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #9013FE 15%, #50E3C2 90%)",
    minWidth: "100%",
    minHeight: "100vh",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  card: {
    maxWidth: "40%",
    minHeight: "20vh",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export default function LoginPage() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid
      className={classes.root}
      spacing={0}
      alignItems="center"
      justify="center"
    >
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Hello World
        </Button>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: tried this, but ti doesn't center the Button in the Card

Comment: Strange. It is centered in the linked sandbox.

Comment: if you increase the size of the card you'll notice they just share the same size, but the button is not centered. Here you can check: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dirac-gcttz?file=/src/App.js